# Join 2 tables in a Single Eloquent Laravel using multiple where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

here I'd like to find the solution to simplify my query to get data using eloquent in Laravel.

```
$room_id = Booking::whereBetween('from', [$request->from, $request->to])
                     ->orWhereBetween('to', [$request->from, $request->to])
                     ->where('from', '<=', $request->from, )
                     ->where('to', '>=', $request->from)
                     ->pluck('room_id');
                     
$rooms = Room::whereNotIn('id', $room_id )->get();
```

So here I have 2 Eloquent operations to get Rooms which not included in the Booking Table with specified requirements. So far I have no problem with it, but can you guys give me best practice to simplify from what I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that 'bookings' relation is written on your Room model.

```
$rooms = Room::whereDoesntHave('bookings', use($request) function($q){ 
    $q->whereBetween('from', [$request->from, $request->to])
    $q->orWhereBetween('to', [$request->from, $request->to])
    $q->where('from', '<=', $request->from, )
    $q->where('to', '>=', $request->from)
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, this one solved my problem. But why when I try to use paginate(), it returns an empty array on the next page?

Answer (score 0):

- Your can refer laravel relationship to add it in model and after that using whereHas to query join table:
  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Example:

- With options

> protected $with = [
> 'product_savour'
> ];

- Relationship

> public function product_savour()
> {
> return $this->hasMany(ProductSavour::class, 'product_id');
> }

- Query

> ```
> $productQuery->whereHas('product_savour', function ($query) use ($filters) {
>                     $query->whereHas('savour', function ($query) use ($filters) {
>                         $query->whereHas('type', function ($query) use ($filters) {
>                             $query->whereIn('id', $filters['savour']);
>                         });
>                     });
>             });
> ```